# advice on php post operation not running

Tags: php, mysql

I have donation page which when the user clicks donate it posts the data to a php file named test.php I am trying this out my first trying to echo the first name and last name but this is not working ultimately I want this php page to run a MySQL query to update the total_Donation row within a database, here is my main php page first.

**Database code which sits at top of file**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","null");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snr", $con);

$names_sql = "SELECT first_Name, last_Name FROM donate WHERE user_ID > 0";
$names_query = mysql_query($names_sql)or die(mysql_error());
$rsNames= mysql_fetch_assoc($names_query);

if(isset($_POST['donation']) && $_POST['donation'] != '')
{
$donation = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['donation']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['first_Name']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['last_Name']);
$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + '{$donation}' WHERE      first_Name = '{$fname}' AND last_Name = '{$lname}'";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my form section of html

```
 form method ="post" action="test.php">
<table>

    <tr><td><label>Runner:</label></td>
    <td>
    <select>
    <?php do{?>
    <option> <?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?> <?php echo $rsNames['last_Name'];?></option>
    <?php } while ( $rsNames= mysql_fetch_assoc($names_query))?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Donation £</label></td><td><input type="text" maxlength="9"    value="0.00" name="donation"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="DONATE"/></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

the option gets all the first names and last names fine when the user hits donate I want it to run the $donation_sql but all i get are errors saying unidentified index, I'm even trying the below in the test.php to simply just echo the first_Name this is giving the same error.

```
<?php

echo $_POST['first_Name'];

?>
```

Can someone please help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","null");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snr", $con);

$names_sql = "SELECT first_Name, last_Name FROM donate WHERE user_ID > 0";
$names_query = mysql_query($names_sql)or die(mysql_error());
?>
<form method ="post" action="test.php">
<table>

    <tr><td><label>Runner:</label></td>
    <td>
    <select name="name">
    <?php
    while($list = mysql_fetch_array($names_query))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $list['first_Name'] . ' ' . $list['last_Name']; ?>">
        <?php echo $list['first_Name'] . ' ' . $list['last_Name']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Donation £</label></td><td><input type="text" maxlength="9" value="0.00" name="donation" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="submit" type="submit" name="send" value="DONATE"/></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","null");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snr", $con);

if(isset($_POST['donation']) && $_POST['donation'] != '')
{
$names = explode(' ',$_POST['name']);
$first_name= $names[0];
$last_name= $names[1];
$donation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['donation']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($first_name);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($last_name);

$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + '" .$donation. "' WHERE  first_Name = '" .$fname. "' AND last_Name = '" .$lname. "'";

echo 'DEBUG (remove after OK): <br>' .$donate_sql. '<br>';
$res = mysql_query($donate_sql);

echo 'Thanks ' .$first_name. ' ' .$last_name. '<br>';

}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

That´s it!

Comment: thanks for the help but that stil doesn't work is showing code when echo starts onwards

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to give a name attribute to the select:

```
<select name="first_Name">
<?php while ( $rsNames= mysql_fetch_assoc($names_query)):?>
 <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rsNames['first_Name']).' '.htmlspecialchars($rsNames['last_Name']);?>"> [option displayed to the user here]</option>
<?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

And of course use the $_POST array, not the $_GET, since you're using the POST method.

Comment: would it not be first name and last name and will making that change run all of my database querys

Comment: Just concatenate/write both values in the value="" attribute

Comment: I'm lost what about the last_Name

Comment: If you want them in the same $_POST index, write both inside the value="", else write only the one you need. Everything between the <option></option> tags will be showed to the user, while what's inside the value="" attribute will be picked up by PHP

Comment: This part of the code was already working its running the donate_sql that is causing the issue that gets the first name and last name and updates the total by the value entered under donation

Answer (score 0):

\make sure you set name for select and you have valua attr in option tag

```
<select name="first_Name">

<otpion value="<?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?>"><?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?> 
        <?php echo $rsNames['last_Name'];?>
</option>

</select>
```